# QML screen orientation lock

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I need to lock the screen to a specific orientation for an android app that I'm making.
is there a way to do that in QML? Google didn't get me any answers. 
I am using Qt 5.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can basically use the `Screen.orientation` property for reading only. See the following example for details:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-window-screeninfo-qml.html

The proper way as of today is to use the Android manifest file for this as done by the Qt Android developer at Digia for his [QtHangMan game](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/12/12/implementing-in-app-purchase-on-android/) which is:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is-

1. Create an out-of-source directory - let's call it "**templates**" (can be anything)
2. Copy the AndroidManifest.xml into "**templates**" from - 
   **`<path to qt installation>/android_armv7/src/android/templates/AndroidManifest.xml`**
3. Edit the copied AndroidManifext.xml with your favorite editor and change the orientation from "*unspecified*" to "*sensorLandscape*" (or anything else you prefer) and save the file.
4. In the qmake file (*.pro) of your project, add the following line -

   **`ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = <path to your templates directory>`** #in case you added the directory one above the source directory, **path to your templates directory = "../templates"**
5. Build and Run. You should now see that the Orientation is fixed to whatever you have specified in the custom AndroidManifest.xml file

To understand what really is happening - here's the [qt reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html), look for ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR

In case the link doesn't work in future, here's the relevant bits -

> "ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR: This variable can be used to specify a
>   directory where additions and modifications can be made to the default
>   Android package template. The androiddeployqt tool will copy the
>   application template from Qt into the build directory, and then it
>   will copy the contents of the ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR on top of
>   this, overwriting any existing files. The update step where parts of
>   the source files are modified automatically to reflect your other
>   settings is then run on the resulting merged package. If you, for
>   instance, want to make a custom AndroidManifest.xml for your
>   application, then place this directly into the folder specified in
>   this variable. You can also add custom Java files in
>   ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR/src."

QtCreator - 4.2.1, Qt - 5.8